# How to return shorter coordinates from Xamarin Geolocation?

Tags: xamarin, geolocation

Instead of coordinates like: Latitude: 99,9999397213696, Longitude: 99,9999990115402 
i would like to get something like this: Lat 99.9999 lon 99.9999.

How can i make geolocation to return me shorter/not so accurate values?

```
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
```

Comment: why don't you just round the results to fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the number as a string you can use a formatter:

```
var latString = $"Lat {location.Latitude:N4}";
```

Where the `N4` is the [string formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), which comes in many variations.

If you actually want to round the double value you can use `Math.Round`:

```
var rounded = Math.Round(location.Latitude, 4);
```

Where the `4` is the number of decimals you want.